# Coding BigInt Division

Tags: division, bigint

Question: A good and efficient algorithm for BigInt division?

Attempted: Polynomial long division, division with ints (overflow remainder), binary long division (any good? Not sure, that's what I have in the post below), quotient guessing division (too many subtractions with large quotients).

I have been trying to code BigInt division for a while. My latest algorithm uses binary division, but I don't think that this is the best method.

So I am looking for some ideas as to what algorithms may be out there ; ).

The language I'm working in doesn't support passing items such as arrays around or various data types. I'm stuck with integers and booleans and global arrays as well as local arrays declared at the top of the function.

I'm working with a word size of 32768 for increased speed, which happens to be 2^15. Because of this, I can quickly and efficiently convert to base 2 and back, which is why I decided to try a binary division algorithm approach.

My first approach caused the remainder to overflow in some situations, but it was extremely fast. My next approach was an idea of polynomial long division. I also tried the quotient idea, although it would fail on extremely big numbers as there would be way too many subtractions involved. Overall, I think that the crappy binary division algorithm may be the best bet ; |.

Numbers get smaller towards the end of the divisor and remainder arrays. They are smaller towards the beginning of the dividend array.

The final answer is stored in binaryDividendBuffer with size binaryDividendBufferSize (quotient) and remainder with size remainderSize (remainder). This thing works with 0 bugs, but I have a feeling that it is just really bad :o.

```
globals

    private static integer array binaryDividendBuffer          //division binary buffer #1 (to be divided)
    private static integer binaryDividendBufferSize                //division binary count #1

    private static integer array binaryBufferDivisor         //division binary buffer #2 (to divide)
    private static integer binaryBufferDivisorSize               //division binary count #2

endglobals
```

Code:

```
local integer currentDividendDigit = binaryDividendBufferSize       //to be divided int digit count
local integer tempDigit2                                            //temp digit 2
local integer tempDigit3                                            //temp digit 3
local integer array remainder                                       //remainder
local integer remainderSize = 0                                     //remainder count
local boolean remainderLessThanDividend                             //is the remainder < divisor?
local integer binaryBufferDividendDigitOffset                       //subtract -1 or 0 (shift the divisor by 1 bit for extra digit)
local boolean gatheredDigits                                        //were bits gatheredDigits?

loop
    //gather bits equal to the length of the divisor only if the current remainder isn't equal to length of divisor and there are bits remaining
    set gatheredDigits = false
    set gatheredDigits = remainderSize != binaryBufferDivisorSize and 0 != currentDividendDigit
    if (gatheredDigits) then
        loop
            exitwhen remainderSize == binaryBufferDivisorSize or 0 == currentDividendDigit

            set currentDividendDigit = currentDividendDigit - 1
            set remainder[remainderSize] = binaryDividendBuffer[currentDividendDigit]
            set remainderSize = remainderSize + 1

            set binaryDividendBuffer[currentDividendDigit] = 0
        endloop
    endif

    //if the remainder is smaller than the divisor and there are no bits left to gather, exit
    if (remainderSize < binaryBufferDivisorSize and 0 == currentDividendDigit) then
        set binaryDividendBuffer[currentDividendDigit] = 0
        exitwhen true
    endif

    //compare the remainder and the divisor to see which one is greater
    set tempDigit2 = 0
    set remainderLessThanDividend = false
    loop
        set remainderLessThanDividend = remainder[tempDigit2] < binaryBufferDivisor[tempDigit2]
        set tempDigit2 = tempDigit2 + 1
        exitwhen tempDigit2 == binaryBufferDivisorSize or remainderLessThanDividend or remainder[tempDigit2] > binaryBufferDivisor[tempDigit2]
    endloop

    //if remainderLessThanDividend and there are bits remaining, add an additional bit
    //set the dividend's current bit to 0 IF bits were gatheredDigits (division taking place)
    //if bits weren't gatheredDigits, then setting it to 0 will set an already divided bit
    if (remainderLessThanDividend) then
        exitwhen 0 == currentDividendDigit

        if (gatheredDigits) then
            set binaryDividendBuffer[currentDividendDigit] = 0
        endif
        set currentDividendDigit = currentDividendDigit - 1
        set remainder[remainderSize] = binaryDividendBuffer[currentDividendDigit]
        set remainderSize = remainderSize + 1
        set binaryBufferDividendDigitOffset = -1        //shift divisor's bits by 1 to account for extra digit in remainder
    else
        set binaryBufferDividendDigitOffset = 0         //don't shift as there is no extra digit in remainder
    endif

    //subtract
    set binaryDividendBuffer[currentDividendDigit] = 1
    set tempDigit2 = remainderSize
    loop
        set tempDigit2 = tempDigit2 - 1

        //if only subtract if the divisor actually has a bit to do subtracting (remainder might have 1 more bit than divisor)
        if (tempDigit2 + binaryBufferDividendDigitOffset > -1) then
            //if the remainder's current bit is remainderLessThanDividend than the divisor's bit, borrow
            if (remainder[tempDigit2] < binaryBufferDivisor[tempDigit2 + binaryBufferDividendDigitOffset]) then
                set remainder[tempDigit2 - 1] = remainder[tempDigit2 - 1] - 1
                set remainder[tempDigit2] = remainder[tempDigit2] + 2
            endif

            //subtract them
            set remainder[tempDigit2] = remainder[tempDigit2] - binaryBufferDivisor[tempDigit2 + binaryBufferDividendDigitOffset]
        endif
        exitwhen 0 == tempDigit2
    endloop

    //cut out all of the 0s in front of the remainder and shift it over
    //000033 -> 33
    //this first loop goes through all of the 0s
    loop
        exitwhen 0 != remainder[tempDigit2] or tempDigit2 == remainderSize
        set tempDigit2 = tempDigit2 + 1
    endloop

    //this loop removes the 0s by shifting over
    if (0 < tempDigit2) then
        if (tempDigit2 == remainderSize) then
            set remainderSize = 0
            set remainder[0] = 0
        else
            set tempDigit3 = 0
            set remainderSize = remainderSize-tempDigit2
            loop
                set remainder[tempDigit3] = remainder[tempDigit3+tempDigit2]
                set remainder[tempDigit3+tempDigit2] = 0
                set tempDigit3 = tempDigit3 + 1
                exitwhen tempDigit3 == remainderSize
            endloop
        endif
    endif

    exitwhen 0 == currentDividendDigit
endloop

//cut out all of the 0s in front of dividend
loop
    exitwhen 0 != binaryDividendBuffer[binaryDividendBufferSize]
    set binaryDividendBufferSize = binaryDividendBufferSize - 1
endloop
```

Comment: You have a long post with a lot of code, but I don't see a question in there. Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site to post on.

Comment: I edited it to make the question clear on the top : ).